# Unix command-Line CSV viewer

Tags: command-line, unix, csv, viewer

Is there a convenient command-line csv viewer, possibly a unix tool or a mod of some tools (e.g. vim or python)?

I find it easy to simply edit CSV files by writing it manually (since all you need to do it comma delimit the columns), but is there a way to view it in a slightly nicer UI on the command-line?

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you want the output formatted?  CSV's are easily to manipulate with shell tools so there's likely a string of four or five shell commands that can format them any way you like for convenient viewing.

Comment: Well, more or less like it's shown in Excel. Having the columns aligned and properly spaced with proper underlining, if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sc is a command-line spreadsheet program that's been around a long time, likely available in your package manager. Here's a Linux Journal intro article to it:

> http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10699

Comment: Not so hot on cygwin it seems: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545813/which-library-defines-these-symbols-nmgetch-kbd-again-initkbd-resetkbd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545813/which-library-defines-these-symbols-nmgetch-kbd-again-initkbd-resetkbd)

Comment: `sc` reads colon-delimited files, not CSV files: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10699?page=0,1

Answer (score 7):

It seems like this question overlaps (at least partially) with my similar question on StackOverflow:

[Command line CSV viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875305/command-line-csv-viewer)

The top answer there is currently:

```
column -s, -t < somefile.csv | less -#2 -N -S
```

(Please see the link for more details.)

Answer (score 5):

There's a tool, [CSVfix](https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvfix), which helps with viewing CSV files.

> [CSVfix](https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvfix) is a command-line stream editor
>   specifically designed to deal with CSV
>   data. With it you can, among other
>   things:
>
> - Convert fixed format, multi-line and DSV files to CSV
> - Reorder, remove, split and merge fields
> - Convert case, trim leading & trailing spaces
> - Search for specific content using regular expressions
> - Filter out duplicate data or data on exclusion lists
> - Perform sed/perl style editing
> - Enrich with data from other sources
> - Add sequence numbers and file source information
> - Split large CSV files into smaller files based on field contents
> - Perform arithmetic calculations on individual fields
> - Validate CSV data against a collection of validation rules
> - Convert between CSV and fixed format, XML, SQL and DSV
> - Summarise CSV data, calculating averages, modes, frequencies etc.

A simple way to view CSV files on the command-line is to pipe the .csv file into the `column` utility with the column delimiter set as a comma:

```
column -s, -t yourfile.csv
```

Comment: Use `column -s, -t yourfile.csv`. Whenever you see `cat file | command` consider `command file` or `command < file` first.

Comment: Yes that's a fair point, I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

The powerful program **vim** have a plugin for .csv files in [CSV Plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=2830) and its screenshot is

[image]

Comment: This never worked for me but seems to be the only alternative in vim ;\

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is already quite old, but I want to add another tool, which I found very convenient:

tabview (https://github.com/TabViewer/tabview)

The header line of the csv file will always stay at the top and there are many more features.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

emacs csv-nav mode will show the csv file and open single records in a text buffer for you to edit and save back to the original buffer